# Draw graphics on a form without lags?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, gdi

Problem with my approach is that image, text or line drawn, lags by maybe 0.2 seconds, when resizing the form. So if you need an image in bottom right corner, it takes that 0.2 seconds to come in place after resize. Also, if you do heavy resizing, it starts lagging down to 1-2FPS, while the form expands on a big screen. Sample code looks like this (VB.NET):

```
Public Class Form1
  Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs)
    MyBase.OnPaint(e)
    Dim icon As Icon = SystemIcons.Exclamation
    Dim imageWidth As Integer = icon.Width
    Dim imageHeight As Integer = icon.Height
    e.Graphics.DrawIcon(icon, Me.ClientRectangle.Right - imageWidth,
                              Me.ClientRectangle.Bottom - imageHeight)
  End Sub
  Private Sub Form1_Resize(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Resize
    Me.Invalidate()
  End Sub
End Class
```

Is there anything that can be done to make it smoother?

Comment: I am not seeing any noticeable delay with the code you posted.

Comment: @JohnKoerner: The weird part is that I've tried on a 5 times slower machine running same Windows 7 and did not find a noticable delay either. So currently it's just my i7 giving me issues. I will do more testing and update the question if I find any pattern.

Comment: Try replacing the `Invalidate()` with `Refresh()`.

Comment: @ja72: just tried, it appears that Invalidate = Refresh in the current context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resizing your window is always going to involve redrawing the image in the new location. However, there are some things you can try that may or may not make the redrawing more efficient.

1. Only invalidate the old and new position of the image, not the whole form. This means that you don't have to paint parts of the window that don't change.
2. Copy the image from the old location to the new location. You have to be careful here to invalidate the right parts of the window, particularly when the window is getting smaller and the old and new image areas overlap.
3. Create a separate control for the image, and move the control to the correct location. The form and the control will then automatically invalidate the correct regions.

Comment: Additionally, paintEventArgs will have an "invalid" rect - identifying the actual bits that need redrawing.  This can often be used for further limiting the rendering required.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how you would invalidate a region that you expect to repaint later (for the above scenario)? I tried using same rectangle I use to paint with Resize event, but it seems everything happened already at that point, so I need to do it before Resize. Tried to override and put it before Mybase.Paint, but still same thing. I am seeing traces of the image when resizing. How big traces are depends on how quickly I am resizing.

Comment: @Neolisk I think you might have to save the previously painted area so that you can invalidate that, then update it to where you intend to paint the image and invalidate that too.

Answer (score 2):

Windows Forms provides a [style setting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.setstyle.aspx) to double buffer the screen. This does a lot of setup for you.

Also, double buffering gets rid of the need to clear the screen so overriding `OnPaintBackground` and returning *without* calling the base class will prevent a lot of work that will not be seen anyway.

For some of the best examples of GDI+ / winforms double buffering check out my [animation](https://web.archive.org/web/20141223080308/http://bobpowell.net/animation.aspx) [examples](https://web.archive.org/web/20140811193726/http://bobpowell.net/doublebuffer.aspx).

Comment: Is it the same as using Form.DoubleBuffered?

Comment: Yep, they are all ways of setting the same thing. You can call the method or set the style explicitly in the form initialization code.

Comment: I tried `DoubleBuffered` - it did not solve the problem. In fact, every time anybody suggested this, it did not help. :)